# PHP problem character set

Tags: php

I have a problem where users upload zipped text files. After  I extract text contents I import them in mysql database. But later when I display the text in browser some characters are garbled. I tried to encode them but I am unable to detect the encoding of the text files with PHP and convert to UTF-8 with iconv or mbstring.

Mysql database charset is UTF-8.

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

is added.

Tried with 
    iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $text_file_contents)

But it simply removes the garbled chars: � which should be either ' or " when I checked manually with Firefox browser. Firefox showed that is ISO-8859-1 but I can not check for every article they send (articles may be in different character set).

How to convert this characters to UTF-8 ?

EDIT:
 This is a modified function I found on 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php
origanlly written by prgss at bk dot ru .

```
function myutf8_detect_encoding($string, $default = 'UTF-8', $encode = 0, $encode_to = 'UTF-8') { 
  static $list = array('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', 'ASCII', 'windows-1250', 'windows-1251', 'latin1', 'windows-1252', 'windows-1253', 'windows-1254', 'windows-1255', 'windows-1256', 'windows-1257', 'windows-1258', 'ISO-8859-2', 'ISO-8859-3', 'GBK', 'GB2312', 'GB18030', 'MACROMAN', 'ISO-8859-4', 'ISO-8859-5', 'ISO-8859-6', 'ISO-8859-7', 'ISO-8859-8', 'ISO-8859-9', 'ISO-8859-10', 'ISO-8859-11', 'ISO-8859-12', 'ISO-8859-13', 'ISO-8859-14', 'ISO-8859-15', 'ISO-8859-16');

  foreach ($list as $item) {
    $sample = iconv($item, $item, $string);
    if (md5($sample) == md5($string)) {

      if ($encode == 1)
      return iconv($item, $encode_to, $string);
      else
      return $item;
    }
  }

  if ($encode == 1)
  return iconv($encode_to, $encode_to . '//IGNORE', $string);
  else
  return $default;
}
```

and in my code I use:

```
myutf8_detect_encoding(trim($description), 'UTF-8', 1)
```

but it still returns garbled characters of this text  “old is gold’’ .

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed tricky.

Detecting an arbitrary string's encoding using `detect_encoding...` is known to be not very reliable (although it *should* be able to distinguish between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 for example - make sure you give it a try first.)

If the auto-detection doesn't work out, there is the option of displaying the content to the user before it gets submitted, along with a drop-down menu to switch between the most used encodings.  Then show a message like

> Please check your submission. If you are seeing incorrect or garbled characters, please change the encoding in the drop-down menu until the content is correct.

Whenever the user changes the drop-down value, your script will pull the content again, use `iconv()` to convert it from the specified encoding to UTF-8, and output the result, until it looks good.

This needs some finesse in designing the User Interface to be understandable for the end user, but it would often be the best option. Especially if you are dealing with users from many different regions or continents with a lot of different encodings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but I could not find any functions with detect_encoding in php or content sniffing technique on internet.

Comment: @user Didn't @Evert below suggest one?

Comment: How is this content sniffing?

Comment: @user maybe "sniffing" is the wrong word here. I changed the wording. But what `mb_detect_encoding()` is essentially nothing else. It searches the content for specific characters and tries to determine from them what encoding is used. This is also the reason why it is so unreliable so often

Comment: Hi, even if I convert with the correct in_charset with iconv the same characters are still garbled but this time they are different:

Comment: and it wont to display here, but the character is a tiny box with 0093 numbers inside.

Comment: @user then it's not the correct incoming charset. `iconv()` works for exactly this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same problem of encoding detection, I made a php function that outputs different information about the string and should make it relatively easy to identify the encoding used.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php (function `hex_chars` by "manixrock(hat)gmail(doink)com").

It shows the values of the characters inside the string, as well as the values of each individual byte. You look at the output and see which of your suspected encodings matches the bytes. You should first familiarize yourself with the various popular encodings like UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8859-X (understand their byte storage). Also make sure you test the string as unaltered as possible (take care how the encoding might change between what PHP outputs and what the browser receives, how the browser displays, or if you get the string from another source like MySQL or a file how that may change the encoding).

This helped me detect that a text had undergone the conversions: (UTF-8 to byte[]) then (ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8). That function helped a lot. Hope it helps you.

Comment: While I was searching on how to detect encoding I found this function:
function detect_encoding($string) { 
  static $list = array('utf-8', 'windows-1251');
 
  foreach ($list as $item) {
    $sample = iconv($item, $item, $string);
    if (md5($sample) == md5($string))
      return $item;
  }
  return null;
}

Comment: @user453984 if you only need to detect between 'utf-8' and 'windows-1251' encodings, then yes. But if it's any other encoding, or some bad combination thereof, then it won't.

Answer (score -1):

Use mb_detect_encoding to find out what encoding is used, then iconv to convert.

Comment: How to use properly mb_detect_encoding to detect charset?

Comment: From the documentation: mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1');

Comment: in my experience, mb_detect_encoding is somewhat unreliable

Comment: How to detect all character sets (ISO-8859-*) ? Should I include all but in what order?

Answer (score -1):

Try to insert right after the mysql connection:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: Not correct. This just tells mysql text will be submitted as UTF-8, which is not the case for the OP.